# App showing force close when installed in my android phone. But runs in emulator

Tags: android

I am able to run my app in emulator and in my friends mobile(Froyo). Mine is xperia mini pro(2.3) in which the app is not getting installed. It gives a force close saying "process com.android.package installer" closed unexpectedly.. Also I am able to install other apks in my phone.

Comment: Please,provide more information about the problem.
Try debugging when you start installing the app and tell us the error message.
Remember,the more details you provide the better is answer we can give you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application must have used some of the API which is not available for the other version and hence it's getting crashed. since you can feel the same for the API demo of higher version installed on the lower version device

Comment: Buddy thnx for the reply.. and mine is not rooted device and hence i cannot check ma log. all I do is install my app in ma device. It gives a force close. And the message "Process com.android.packageinstaller" failed unexpectedly. But it works on other devices. It might be an issue because of not signing the apk??

Comment: Nothing related to signing, since all the device can install the non signed application. if the package installer is getting crash means it has something to do with device and that particular application. check with other application to for same device

Comment: Drax I did it. And they are gettin installed in ma device. Thats not an issue and moreover i have downloaded nearly 20-30mapps from the market. None of it showed an issue like this..

Comment: nope. i install the apks normally. Apart from market apps, I put some apks downloaded from net to ma device and open the apk file and install thru astro. All other apks are gettin installed well... I have no clues why it shoes like this.